# Passing shared_ptr to function is not working

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

i have type called Fan,
whenever i try to write this function:

```
void connect(shared_ptr<Fan>&);
```

it's not compiled,and this is what i get in the terminal :

```
fanBook_example.cpp:34:22: error: no matching function for call to 
âmtm::FanBookServer::connect(std::shared_ptr<mtm::Fan>&)â
fanBook_example.cpp:34:22: note: candidate is:
In file included from Fan.h:3:0,
                 from FanBookPost.h:5,
                 from mtm_ex4.h:36,
                 from fanBook_example.cpp:16:
FanBookServer.h:39:7: note: void mtm::FanBookServer::connect(int&)
```

im trying to pass shared_ptr as parameter , and it not working any idea how to it ?
thank you

edit :

I'm trying to implement connect function which is supposed to take shared_ptr for example:

```
auto fan = std::make_shared<Fan>(1,"Bob");
server->connect(fan)
```

Fan type is at Fan.h (included) and its inside namespace called mtm
and also the FanBookServer is inside of namespace mtm.

Comment: Somehow, your compiler is thinking that connect is taking an int&. Check all your declarations.

Comment: It's hard to tell with this much info. Could you give us the code where it is called and implemented?

Comment: @Emad4U It looks like the compiler sees `connect(int&)` but doesn't see `connect(shared_ptr<Fan>&)`. It can be caused by method name hiding if `connect(shared_ptr<Fan>&)` is declared in a base class of `FanBookServer`. In that case you need to add `using BaseClass::connect;` to `FanBookServer` or change the name of `connect` method in one of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Always start by looking at the *first* compiler error (or warning), not the *last* one. Compiler errors tend to "cascade": the compiler first sees something like

```
void connect(shared_ptr<Fan>&);
```

and emits an error message something like

```
test2.cc:2:14: error: no template named 'shared_ptr'; did you mean 'std::shared_ptr'?
void connect(shared_ptr<Fan>&);
             ^~~~~~~~~~
             std::shared_ptr
```

Depending on the particular version of your compiler, it may very well replace the unknown type with `int` and continue on its way — helpfully trying to give as many errors in one run as possible. (This isn't entirely sarcastic; in rare cases a program *will* have multiple independent syntax errors, and the programmer will appreciate being told about all of them at once.)

Anyway, in your case the compiler gets down to the place where you're trying to pass a `std::shared_ptr<Fan>` to a function prototyped as `int&` (well, really `<unknown-type>&`, but it's the same thing to this compiler), and so it complains.

---

On an unrelated note, you probably don't need to be passing the `shared_ptr` itself by reference — that's only useful if you're planning to modify the caller's pointer itself (i.e., if you're using it as an out-parameter). You should probably use either `void connect(shared_ptr<Fan> p)` (if it needs to mess with ownership) or `void connect(const Fan& fan)` (if it doesn't need to mess with ownership).